# How to get comments that rate the service from many Facebook pages (from restaurants) for sentiment analysis in 2018? (Twitter is not good enough)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, sentiment-analysis

**I need to know If I need to give up on Facebook and just use Twitter for my purposes** (if so, just tell me to use Twitter). I want to use pages I don't own.

I am doing this same process in Twitter, but Twitter doesn't have pages that rate places, services or things in general with comments and a rating system (or atleast the ones I need from one city with specific places).

Twitter has much more liberty to get comments from any @user_name but its not good enough for a sentiment analysis specific assignment I need to do. I am trying to get facebook comments or posts from multiple facebook pages (pages from restaurants) based on the comments used for ratings and download them to a csv or database with any program or by coding (Preferably Node.js, javavascript or php) for sentiment analysis (this is very easy with Twitter!). How can I achieve this with all the policies and restrictions Facebook has in 2018??

I have some questions with reference to facebook:

- Will an app_id and app_secret by making an app in 2018 give me an access token to get the comments I need from ANY page and download them with graph api?
- Is facebook graph API the only way to get comments or posts to download them?
- Why doesn't any type of code or programs before and even right now in 2018 work anymore to get comments? (I get the errors below with either programs or graph api).

I tried to use Graph API from facebook for 2 different pages using GET and POST and I get some errors that I didn't have trouble with 9 months ago (**this happens with every page I try to search with code in node.js, javascrip, php or the graph API from facebook**):

```
GET/v3.1/OMENbyHPLatam/feed

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "CXg962vUvjY"
  }
}

POST/v3.1/minecraft/feed

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "EZvhzuk/UHL"
  }
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. What is are you confused about?

Comment: @WizKid 8 months ago it didn't show those errors. I just had to press one button and got the comments I wanted. Are there any tutorials to overcome this error or youtube video? I don't find any recent videos that fix the problem quick and easy.

Comment: That is correct. Facebook changed stuff.